# Can't upload a video via S3 presigned URLs from JS code but from Postman it works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios, pre-signed-url

I have a pre-signed S3 URL and I can't upload a video when I call this link via Axios but I can when I do it via Postman.

Presigned URL creation:

```js
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner';
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

const myClient = new S3Client(myConfig);
const commandParams: PutObjectCommandInput = {
      Bucket: 'placeholder_name',
      Key: 'some_key',
      ContentType: `video/${contentType}`,
    };

const url = await getSignedUrl(myClient, new PutObjectCommand(commandParams);, {
      expiresIn: 3600,
    });

/** URL goes back to the front-end, nextjs app */
return url
```

The URL starts with our domain name, region, etc., then the video name and all the parameters Amazon creates, the link works as you will see later on.

Then, on the front end when I call that URL like this, it fails:

```js
 uploadVideoViaPresignedUrl(urlFromServer: string, keyFromServer: string, files: File[]) {
   const formData = new FormData();

   for (const file of files) {
      formData.append(keyFromServer, file);
   }

   return axios({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: urlFromServer
      data: formData,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
    });
  }
```

I tried with and without the headers, and all I get from axios is `network_error` and in the browser's network tab, this `PUT` request fails with `NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI`

But then when I call the same URL in Postman, with 0 extra configurations it succeeds (notice the 200 status code) and it even uploads a new file every time to my S3 bucket (I have checked):

[image: Post man results]

So, I think the issue is from my axios code, it's just a PUT request, does it need anything extra or something? any ideas? Thanks.

Edit:

I double-checked the network tab and now I see this:
[image]

Comment: Are you opening the HTML for your frontend using a local file URL (i.e. `C:\Users\...\index.html`?

Comment: What's the URI you are trying to hit? Does the browser give any further information in the error console of the request tab about the error? Any chance this is a CORS issue (postman doesn't deal in CORS because it's not a browser)?

Comment: It might be a CORS issue yeah @AdamJenkins

Comment: No, it's a running app in development mode @Quassnoi

Comment: @Yuniac: so, just to clarify, you're using http to access the app? Is it hosted on localhost? This could be a `CORS` issue (and you do need to set up CORS on the S3 side for it to work), but the error message would likely be different. What browser are you using? Do you see something called "Preflight message" with the header `OPTIONS` in your browser's network tab or console?

Comment: I think you are right, it's CORS. Yes, I am trying to connect from a web app. I have updated my question to include another screenshot (using Firefox). @Quassnoi Thank you.
Edit: Yes, there's an options request too now next to the PUT request, I have included a screenshot. Any idea how to configure S3 to deal with this CORS issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure [CORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html) on your S3 bucket and whitelist your web application's domain.

Your CORS policy could look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://my-application.example.com"
        ]
    }
]
```

Before issuing a `PUT` request, your browser would send a separate `OPTIONS` request, called "preflight", basically asking the server this:

> You're not the server I loaded my JS code from, but the JS code coming from `my-application.example.com` is asking me to upload some data to you. Could you please double-check I'm not being a [confused deputy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem)?

This way, S3 knows that code loaded from `my-application.example.com` has a valid use case to upload data to this bucket, and confirms the browser's preflight request.

Comment: I think this might be it, I will check and once it works I will accept your answer (so if it's not it other people can still answer, etc.), thanks a lot.

Comment: You were right, thanks a lot man